# Embed an Array into Dict structure in plist

Tags: ios, plist

I'm beginner in iOS.  Every resource I find has only key string pairs in the dicts inside plists.

```
<key></key>
<string></string>
```

I am wondering if it possible to have one of the objects in the   structure to be a key pair in which the object is an array.  In my plist I have a structure as follows.  The first dictionary holds a variable number of key string pairs which may or may not be present in the plist.  My code checks to see if the presence of certain keys exist.  However, I want to add an array which will contain as many entrees as needed to this initial dictionary.  The code below doesn't work, but it is what I would like to be able to do.

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>SomeTitle</string>
             .
             .
             .
        <key>filters</key>
        <array>???

        </array>???
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: Yes, you can have an array as a value in the dictionary. Use Xcode's plist editor to do this. Or at least use it to get you started. Much less error prone than editing the raw XML.

Comment: The plists are going to be placed on a server, written by other developers without access to xcode, or a mac in general. So I have been looking for the correct way to code up the XML and then parse it in code.

Comment: That's fine. Create a sample plist in Xcode and use that as a basis for the actual plist files you need to create without Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you to be able to load the plist file using the `initWithContentsOfFile:` method, it needs to be a proper plist file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>PageTitle</key>
        <string>Title</string>
        <key>Filters</key>
        <array>
             <dict>
                 <key>Filter</key>
                 <string>SomeFilter</string>
                 <key>Param</key>
                 <string>SomeParam</string>
             </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

Also, this line:

```
NSMutableArray* filters = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[dict objectForKey:@"Filters"]] retain];
```

should just be:

```
NSMutableArray* filters = [dict[@"Filters"] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: ok ill try that second line thanks.  I should have added the plist header, i just coppied over the array part, it does in fact have the proper plist format, thats my bad.

Comment: this does in fact answer my original question about how to get the array in a plist so I am accepting.  The dict variable still only contains the 'PageTitle' key, no 'Filters', but that is a different question all together.

Answer (score 0):

using

```
<key>SomeKey</key>
<array>
</array>
```

us correct after all.  My parsing code just didnt recognize it.

I am using the parsing code

```
NSMutableArray* propertyList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [propertyFile objectAtIndex:0];
NSMutableArray* filters = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[dict objectForKey:@"Filters"]] retain];
```

with the plist of

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>PageTitle</key>
        <string>Title</string>
        <key>Filters</key>
        <array>
             <dict>
                 <key>Filter</key>
                 <string>SomeFilter</string>
                 <key>Param</key>
                 <string>SomeParam</string>
             </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
 </array>
```

Comment: What "parsing" code? Why don't you just load the plist into an array using `NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:`?

Comment: I am but it is not recognizing it.

Comment: Sorry, what edit? Make sure your file is a proper plist file. This must include the standard xml header and doctype plus the `plist` root tag.

Comment: sorry it didnt post, is there now.  the dict variable only has one entry, and that is for the PageTitle key.

Comment: See my answer for the solution.